# python flask partically update webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to use python flask framework to build a webpage. This webpage is a dashboard, which has two divs. The first div is a table, each row of which is the info for a certain stock. The second div is a chart which shows the price curve for one of the stocks in the first table.

I would like to refresh the second chart based on the selection from the first table. For example, if I click on the name of stock A in the first table, the price curve for A is then showed in the second chart.

One way to implement this, is to link each stock name to a different url, and have a html file associated with each url address. A series of render_template functions have to be defined in the view.py script.

I wonder if there's a more generic way to implement this. Maybe one function definition and one html template would be enough for all stocks in the table?

thanks!

Comment: why not try the jQuery ? when user clicks the stock A and get the relevent info from server and return json and parse the json to update the chart...

Comment: create get and post api calls in your flask application and then retrieve data from server via those api calls using jQuery.

Comment: Have you thought about going with a client side JS Framework? ReactJS sounds perfect! Happy to help refactor, if interested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate URL in flask using url_for(). So maybe your template to generate charts can use url_for('/stock', stock_name='GOOG'). Which will embed the route /stock/GOOG into a link to show a chart for GOOG.

Then you can use a nested template to show the chart div when the above route is called.

Here is link to the relevant documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#url-building
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/templateinheritance/